# reading from different files and using strtok on strings

Tags: c, string, file, strtok

so this is a code that reads 3 strings **(orig // test1 // orig_copy)** from 2 different files **(firstline // secondline)**and calls divide_string to use strtok and take tokens and store them in **(token_orig // token_test // token_orig_copy)**,
 ***--> this is the problem :*** 
- when i put the three lines in main it does compile and take token from all 3 strings and "Done ." in the end.
-but when i try the next three lines (notice how i changed "**HAHAHAH**" to "**HAHAHAHA**", that little changing changes everything and make the program stops at printf("for the string number two :"); .
i hope i cleared the problem
 PS : you can past copy the program so you can compile yourself easily

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const char s[4] = " ,.";
int divide_string(char* thestring,char** destination)
{
    int i=0;
     char* token=strtok(thestring,s);
     destination[i]=malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
     strcpy(destination[i],token);
     i++;
     printf("the word %d is 'tokened' \n",i);
     while(token!=NULL)
     {
              token =strtok(NULL,s);
         if (token != NULL)
         {
             destination[i]=malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
             strcpy(destination[i],token);
             printf("the word %d is 'tokened' \n",i);
             ++i;
         }
     }
     return i;
}
void main ()
{ //TRY THESE THREE LINES THAT WORKS<-----------------------------
 char orig[]= "does work HAHAHAH";
char orig_copy[] = "does work HAHAHAH";
char test1[]="does work HAHAHAH";
//    char orig[]= "doesnt work HAHAHAHA";
//    char orig_copy[] = "doesnt work HAHAHAHA";
//    char test1[]="doesnt work HAHAHAHA";
    char *token_orig[81];
char *token_test[81];
char *token_orig_copy[81];
strcpy(orig_copy,orig);
printf("for string number one : \n");
int max_orig = divide_string(orig,token_orig);
printf("for string number two : \n");
int a        = divide_string(orig_copy,token_orig_copy);
printf("for string number three : \n");
int max_test = divide_string(test1,token_test);
printf("%s-",token_orig[0]);
printf("%s-",token_orig[1]);
printf("%s-\n",token_orig[2]);
printf("%s-",token_orig_copy[0]);
printf("%s-",token_orig_copy[1]);
printf("%s-\n",token_orig_copy[2]);
printf("%s-",token_test[0]);
printf("%s-",token_test[1]);
printf("%s-\n",token_test[2]);
    printf("done .");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and define what "...doesn't work..." means in this context. It looks like you're using something called `s` to define the delimiter characters, but nowhere is `s` defined. It would help if you'd post something that could be compiled. Thanks.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(token)+1);` bad bad bad, --> `malloc(strlen(token)+1);` and even then, you must check `token != NULL`

Comment: There are all sorts of other things wrong. You don't check the result of `fopen` or of `fgets`, you make a string copy and then remove `newline` from *both*,

Comment: Instead of just this excerpt from your code, please create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the question is edited, i made a small program that explains the problem, thanks for looking again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since token is a pointer, `sizeof(token)` gives you the size of the pointer variable (4 or 8 bytes probably), NOT the number of chars in the string it points to!  You want:

```
strlen(token) + 1
```

instead (+1 for the \0).

About the only time sizeof is useful for character strings is literals like:

```
sizeof("Hello World")
```

Comment: Or for arrays declared within the same scope where sizeof may be used to return the array size

Comment: True, but for arrays used for holding character strings this may be misleading, for example, given: `char blah[80] = "blah, blah, blah";` then `sizeof(blah)` is 80, not `sizeof("blah, blah, blah")`.

Comment: Point well taken. I was generally thinking along the lines of `char blah[] = "blah, blah, blah";`, but I'm sure some would do `char blah[80] = "blah, blah, blah";`

Comment: i edited the question and tried what you said and it works but on my program it doesn't which brings to this question : what is the difference betweeen a char *name; and a char name[] and a char read from a file ?

Comment: Here are some resources for arrays vs. pointers: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-5/ http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c http://c-faq.com/aryptr/